# why same variable cannot be declared by both var and let

Tags: javascript

```
// At global scope
```

`window.a = 42;` and `var a = 42;` are same

Then why this runs perfectly

```
// At global scope
window.a = 42;    // Creates binding in the outer global environment
let a = "answer"; // Creates binding in the inner global environment
console.log(a);   // Shows "answer"
```

But it shows error

```
// At global scope
var a = 42;    
let a = "answer";
```

Also for second case `var a` would be assigned in global memory while `let a` would be assigned in script memory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776079/do-let-statements-create-properties-on-the-global-object

Comment: There’s a difference between variables and properties. See [var vs this in Javascript object](/q/4946625/4642212). Note that `var` is much more lax in general.

Comment: because the second is a **redeclaration**,

Comment: @MisterJojo for second case `var a` would be assigned in global memory while `let a` would be assigned in script memory.

Comment: @srrsre There is no “script memory” and “global memory”. But these terms may be helpful: [global Environment Record](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-global-environment-records) and [declarative Environment Record](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-declarative-environment-records), and the different semantics between `var` and `let` during [ScriptEvaluation](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-scriptevaluation) and [function calls](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function-calls-runtime-semantics-evaluation).

Comment: so what ? this remains a redeclaration on the same level of scope

Comment: @MisterJojo yes at same level but at different memory.

Comment: no there are no different memories, with the 'let' and 'const' syntax, the javascript language has become more strict  against those who juggle with variable names and usages.

Comment: Then why in chrome it show two different scoped @MisterJojo

Comment: Chrome use V8 (JS engine) and and mozilla another (I forgot the name JägerMonkey?) what they do in their kitchen is their own business, the only thing that matters is that they respect the specifications set out in ECMAscript

Answer (score 1):

> `window.a = 42;` and `var a = 42;` are same

Not exactly, no. See [What is the purpose of the var keyword and when should I use it (or omit it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1470488/1048572).

`window.a` is just a property access and doesn't follow any scoping rules.

`var a` and `let a` are both variable declarations, and `let` complains when you mistakenly declare the same variable twice. This is not different in the global scope than it is in a local scope. See [why we can't re-declare variable with let in global situation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52606912/1048572), [What's the difference between using "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/762011/1048572) and [Redeclaring a variable using `let` results in “Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of let …”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47807204/1048572).